# Angular dynamic content using modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-module

So my application is growing and becomming a fullscale enterprize application.

Because of this clients of my application has different request as to how it should look and feel.

Some of them want all of the content and some of them wants only parts of the content.

Because of these request we have to allow the users to costimize the application as they see fit.

Now ive been searching online to find a solution to how you might deal with this and i want to hear your opinion on the following:

---

The application contains the following features:

- Chat
- Forum
- Usermanagement
- Games

Now all of these features are used on different pages, some of the features are bound together to make 1 page an example of this might be:

[image]

Now the idea was to encapsulate all of these features into an `angular module`.

And each of the feature components into `directives`

using the above picture the `game highscore` would be a directive located in the `GameModule`.

Say for instance that our clients does not want to use the `Game` feature. Then all `directives` located in this `module` would not be visible / disabled.

Looking at the `angular` documentation this should be possible. But i need you guys opinion on this? Is is possible to do such a thing and if so **how**?

I hope you guys understand my question i really want to use best pratice to solve this issue and as far as i can read Modules is the best way of doing this.

Comment: If you are using the metronic framework, can you put in comments the `game.html` page in `sidebar.html` ? Then you won't have the Game feature, maybe i'm mistaken

Comment: @BipBip im not using the metronic framework